# Parametrizar ruta ficheros temporales en Servlet 3.0

Tags: java, servlets, multipart

Estoy realizando un servlet al cual se sube un documento.

Mediante el API de java Servlet 3.0 estoy indicando en el `web.xml` la propiedad:

```
<multipart-config>  
      <location>C:\temp</location>
</multipart-config>
```

Pero me surge el problema de que esta ruta debe ser parametrizable mediante un fichero de propiedades. 
¿Existe alguna manera de especificar esa ruta en tiempo de ejecución?

Comment: Podríás definir el servlet por anotaciones y así lo harías de forma programática. Algo como [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145489/multipartconfig-override-in-web-xml)

Comment: Con anotaciones tendría el mismo problema. Me podría ayudar el último comentario que habla de editar @MultipartConfig en la clase. Pero esto es precisamente lo que no sé cómo hacerlo, el programaticamente editar la configuración de multipart